# Show select certificate dialog in webview

Tags: android, azure, webview, ssl-certificate

I'm using webview in my app to load authentication form in a Microsoft Azure website.
When loading the same website using Chrome or Samsung Internet app, a popup shows that allows me to select and approve certificate.
How can I implement the same thing using webview.

[image]

Comment: if you need a popup to be shown from appside, you can use intercept url method where you intercept a particular url in webview and trigger a appside event based on the url